# How to use Atomics Counter for counting operation order of randomly occuring operations on different threads?

Tags: haskell

What I'd like to do is something like this where every time one of these `print` actions occurs it updates the counter to ensure that the next subsequent occurrence of a print action will always have the correct order in which it occurred among any of the possible `print` actions that may occur across multiple threads shown by the counter. The problem in my example is that if the `IORef` is read at the same time between threads then two or more `print` actions will have the same counter value. From what I've read it seems that using the Data.Atomics.Counter library would solve this problem but i am having a really hard time understanding how to use it do so. Can anyone show me an example or try to explain it to me please?

```
main = do
         myref <- newIORef 1 :: IO (IORef Int)
         void(forkIO (forever $ do ref <- readIORef myref
                                   print ("hi " ++ show (ref))
                                   modifyIORef myref (+1) ))
         void(forkIO (forever $ do ref <- readIORef myref
                                   print ("hey " ++ show (ref))
                                   modifyIORef myref (+1) ))
         forever $ do ref <- readIORef myref
                      print ("hello " ++ show (ref))
                      modifyIORef myref (+1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an [`MVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) for this.

```
inc mvar = forever $ do
    v <- takeMVar mvar
    print v
    putMVar mvar (v+1)

main = do
    mvar <- newMVar 1
    forkIO (inc mvar)
    forkIO (inc mvar)
    inc mvar
```

It is important that the `print` occur between `takeMVar` and `putMVar`, while the `MVar` is empty; otherwise another thread may empty the `MVar` and execute its `print`.

Comment: So I understand this a little better, you’re saying that in the event that (takeMVar mvar) occurs at the same time between threads one thread will always succeed in taking it while the other one will lock I’m guessing and have to wait for the thread that succeeded to refill the mvar with its increment?

Comment: Thank you! I have implemented this in my program and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`atomicModifyIORef'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:atomicModifyIORef-39-). It would look something like:

```
increment ref = forever do
  val <- atomicModifyIORef' ref \old -> (old + 1, old)
  print val

main = do
  ref <- newIORef 0
  forkIO $ increment ref
  forkIO $ increment ref
  increment ref
```

Comment: Do you think there’s an advantage to using this method over @DanielWagner ’s answer?

Comment: Be careful! This does not guarantee that the `print`s occur in order (and I have even observed them out of order to double-check before writing this comment).

Comment: @Anon: If you don't care about the order of prints, just that "two or more print actions might have the same value", then they're equivalent. I thought atomic IORef operations might be faster than MVars, but a quick benchmark suggests that this is false for at least some cases. Overall, the MVar solution seems better.